# Why does Atom Editor break for one user but not another on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, atom-editor

I've noticed lately that some of my atom packages are breaking after updating. I have two users on my computer that I switch between and I use atom on both. The strange part is that the packages will work on one user but not another.

What's going on?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is two fold.

First of all, the auto-updater for atom is broken for OSX. 
See https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2860

But it's only broken for Atom, not the packages. So your packages are starting to assume things about Atom that aren't true.

Secondly, packages are installed per user, but atom is shared on your system. That means if you manually "update" Atom by deleting it and reinstalling, then some of the old stuff will hang around in your `~/.atom` folder. This is easy to fix in that all you have to do is delete `~/.atom`. Next time you open Atom it will create a new one for you.

The downside is that you just **deleted all of your packages** so you'll have to go get them again.

Of course, you can move the packages first and put them back in (`.atom/packages`) to save you the hassle if you have a lot of custom packages. And you could hang on to your config.cson to save your settings also . . . but hopefully this won't be an issue for much longer.